# Koa GET return result immediately to the client and do something afterward

Tags: node.js, koa

I'm writing an io.js and Koa API and I have a GET route that I use to pass data to the API and return OK to the user immediately. Basically I don't care about the result that the GET request will return, I just want to pass the data. This is why I want to return "OK" to the client then he makes the GET request as soon as possible and then process the data from the request.

My code so far is as follows:

```
app.use(route.get("/passData", function*(){
    this.body = "OK";
    yield doSomeWork(this.query);
});

function *doSomeWork(query){
   // do work
   // the code below should be triggered when the client receives the OK message
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If I remove `yield` `doSomeWork` is not executed.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to `yield` on `doSomeWork`--that tells Koa to wait, which is exactly what you do **not** want.

```
app.use(route.get("/passData", function*(){
    this.body = "OK";
    doSomeWork(this.query); // REMOVE YIELD
});
```

Since `doSomeWork` is just a plain old asynchronous function now, it's shouldn't be a generator. (If you leave the `*` there, you'll be calling a generator, which does absolutely nothing other than to create an iterator which will then be thrown away.)

```
function doSomeWork(query){ // REMOVE ASTERISK
   // do work
   // the code below should be triggered when the client receives the OK message
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without removing `yield`? Inside the `doSomeWork` function I am using  a generator functions to insert data into my database, so if I do not use `yield` it will not work, or I'll have to rewrite a lot of code.

Comment: Don't quite understand. If you put a `yield` before `doSomeWork`, then Koa will wait for it to finish. As I understand your question, you do not want that. If `doSomeWork` is a generator yielding promises that you want to execute in sequence, then invoke it with `co`.